# Cannot invoke 'isEqualToString' with an argument list of type '(String)' (from closure)

Tags: swift

This problem stems from having two different conditions for comparing a struct.

Typically, I'd like the struct to be unique if its id is unique. But that is not part of the problem here.. here, I need to build a unique set from them where uniqueness comes from multiple conditions. I'm building an array of *condition* closures and then testing each in a custom `TimeSeries` class, that's the plan (although a way to override a set's conditional would let me use a simple just just fine). But I'm running into an issue with the closures themselves.

```
{(_ entry: TimeSeriesEntry, _ set: [TimeSeriesEntry]) -> Bool in
    return !set.contains({ item in item.id.isEqualToString(entry.id) })
}
```

I'm not clear why that reports `Cannot invoke 'isEqualToString' with an argument list of type '(String)'` TimeSeriesEntry.id is defined as `String` not (String):

```
struct TimeSeriesEntry: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let uid: String
    let date: Date
    let apps: [String:Double]
    let locations: [String:Bool]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isEqualToString` belongs to `NSString`. In native Swift it's much easier

```
{(entry, set) -> Bool in // the underscores and types are unused in Swift 3+
    return !set.contains { $0.id == entry.id }
}
```

This could be more efficient

```
!set.map{$0.id}.contains(entry.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if entry's `id` is equal to `id` property of some element from `set`

```
return !set.contains { $0.id == entry.id }
```